# How to fix 'NoSuchMessageException' when MessageSource#getMessage is called

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to read a property in the messages.properties-File. But when I call

```java
messageSource.getMessage("property", null, Locale.getDefault())
```

I'm getting a NoSuchMessageException.

I already tried to rename my messages.properties-File to messages_de_DE.properties and use Locale.GERMANY but there is no difference.

The file is located in src/main/resources

This is my starterclass:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Start extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Start.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        final ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("classpath*:messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator(final MessageSource messageSource) {
        final LocalValidatorFactoryBean bean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        bean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource);
        return bean;
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you want to display it on HTML? if yes, when using Thymeleaf just do `th:text="${messageLabel}"` or with JSP `<spring:message code="messageLabel"/>` and change your properties to messages_de.properties format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
@Configuration
public class MessageConfig {

    private final MessageSource source;
    private final MessageSourceAccessor accessor;


    @Autowired
    public MessageConfig(MessageSource messageSource) {
        this.accessor = new MessageSourceAccessor(this.source = messageSource, new Locale("de", "DE"));
    }


    @Bean
    public Validator validator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean factory = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        factory.setValidationMessageSource(this.source);
        return factory;
    }

    public String get(String msg) {
        try {
            Assert.hasText(msg, "message code must be not blank");
            return this.accessor.getMessage(msg.trim());
        } catch (NoSuchMessageException e) {
            return '{' + msg + '}';
        }
    }
}
```

Please, use existing `MessageSource` and put you properties files to `/src/main/resources`.
Also, try to rename your message file as `messages_de.properties`.

Comment: Thanks your answer helped me to fix it. I removed my custom Bean definitions and it worked.